# how to know value is added in simplecursoradapter

Tags: android, simplecursoradapter

I need to know, there is any alert function for `SimpleCursorAdapter` when value is added? What I want is

1. I open `MainActivity`, there is `ListView` integrated with
   `SimpleCursorAdapter` added data by background services.
2. When value is added by background services, I want to refresh `ListView` and want to
       know how many new value is added. (don't want to use notification).

Just like `AddAll()` and `notifyDataSetChanged()` of `ArrayAdapter`.

It can be possible?

Comment: a simple cursor adapter like all other adapters does have a notify dataset changed method/

Comment: how to know and how to refresh list dynamically?

Comment: yes true a cursor loader and content provider will manage things for you, cursor.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri); through this method. In the case of a cursor i think you will have to perform a requery.

Comment: please look at http://android-er.blogspot.in/2011/06/add-data-to-sqlite-database-with.html

Comment: cited from the android developer site, cursor.requery is deprecated 

**requery()
This method was deprecated in API level 11. Don't use this. Just request a new cursor, so you can do this asynchronously and update your list view once the new cursor comes back.**

Comment: and please check this too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16937839/android-how-to-requery-a-cursor-to-refresh-listview-after-deleting-database-row?answertab=votes#tab-top

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this to set a content observer on the database and use [CursorLoader](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/CursorLoader.html) to load data asynchronously.

Answer (score 0):

Request a new cursor on addition of new records

cited:

```
requery()
This method was deprecated in API level 11. Don't use this. Just request a new cursor, so   you can do this asynchronously and update your list view once the new cursor comes back.
```