# Swipe to delete in a list using RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, swipe-gesture

I am trying to get the swipe-to-delete feature in my `recyclerview`. I am using `onSwiped()` method of `ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback`.
I get the swipe animation, and the swiped row collapses, when I use `adapter.notifyItemRemoved()` method. I checked the row data gets deleted from database. But, the deleted row again is regenerated and displayed on the `recyclerview` at the same position.

```
  @Override
  public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int swipeDir) {

         ListOfItemsRecyclerViewCursorAdapter adapter = (ListOfItemsRecyclerViewCursorAdapter) rv.getAdapter();

         int position = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
         long itemIdToBeRemoved = rv.getAdapter().getItemId(position);

         //Deletes the item from sqlite database
         mDBManager.deleteItem(itemIdToBeRemoved);      

         adapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);

         // Using notifyItemRangeChanged, the swiped row does not collapse, but stays as a blank row.
         adapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(position, adapter.getItemCount());

         //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
         //Tried the following - but did not work
         //getLoaderManager().initLoader(1, null, ListOfItemsFragment.this);

        }
```

Seeing a few other SO questions, I tried to use  adapter`.notifyItemRangeChanged()` method, but that stops the collapsing animation of the row, and just leaves a blank row. 
[Blank row on swipe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tl6bs.png)

I am using a Loader to load the cursor for the adapter from SQLite database. So I also tried to call `initloader()` method, but that also did not work.

Could you please help me solve this problem. I have tried searching for the solution on Stack Overflow but have not been able to solve the problem.

Thanks

Comment: How do you populate your `RecyclerView`? I can imagine that your data is still in the used list.

Comment: I am populating the RecyclerView with data from SQLite database, using a custom cursor RecyclerView adapter. The cursor is loaded using a loader. Yes, it looks like the dataset is not updating. I don't understand what is causing it.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have some sort of `list` of data inside your `adapter`. If yes, delete the item on the corresponding position of the deleted row.

Also, try to call `viewHolder.setIsRecyclable(false);`

Your `onSwiped` should somehow look like this:

```
@Override
public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
                    // your original stuff here, db deletion etc.
                    // don't forget to delete the data inside the adapter
                    viewHolder.setIsRecyclable(false);
                    adapter.notifyItemRemoved(pos);
                }
```

According to your comment, you are using [this adapter](https://gist.github.com/quanturium/46541c81aae2a916e31d)? If so, I think you also need to call `swapCursor` or `changeCursor`. Have you seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16937839/android-how-to-requery-a-cursor-to-refresh-listview-after-deleting-database-row)?

Also, in your question, you are also using `adapter.notifyItemRangeChanged`, `adapter.notifyItemRemoved` should be enough.

Comment: I don't have any list in the adapter, I am getting the data from a cursor. I thought notifyItemRemoved() was to remove the item from the adapter. How do I remove item from the cursor? Do I have to load the cursor again?

Comment: @sofan cursor itself doesn't have data, it is just a pointer to your database. Have you tried `setIsRecyclable` and `notifyItemRemoved`?

Comment: I did try..but I still get a blank row on swipe. It doesn't collapse the row. I am using the cursor adapter from [link]https://gist.github.com/quanturium/46541c81aae2a916e31d . I am wondering if there is something different I need to do to use this adapter.

Comment: Earlier, I had tried using swapCursor() in onLoadFinished() callback method. It had not worked. But, that you mentioned it, I looked into it again. And, I was able to solve my problem. I had not overridden the swapCursor() method in my subclass of the adapter to swap the instance variable holding the cursor. To load the updated cursor, I called loader's onContentChanged() method, after deleting the item from database, in onSwiped() method. Interestingly, I didnt need to use any of the notifyItem...() methods. I hope this is the right way to solve it. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Use

`adapter.remove(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());`

```java
@Override
public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
     // delete your da entry then...
 
     Toast.makeText(activity, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     adapter.remove(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
    
     // if I emptied the entire list...draw background 
     if( adapter.getItemCount()==0 ){
          SwipeRefreshLayout refresh = (SwipeRefreshLayout) activity.findViewById(R.id.container);
          refresh.setBackground( ContextCompat.getDrawable(activity, R.drawable.background_null) );
     }
}
```

Comment: how do I write the remove(int position) method  for an adapter using cursor? I also want the collapsing animation, so I guess I ll have to call notifyItemRemoved() also.

Comment: I cannot edit property my answer now, but in OnSwipe you have to do something with your data entry. The animations will still there

Answer (score 0):

You can see this example at github:

https://github.com/nemanja-kovacevic/recycler-view-swipe-to-delete